# R - Regex text extraction which recognizes numeric values of more than 1 number

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to extract information from a string using a combination of `gregexpr` and `substr`. Each string has a phase beginning with a word and ending in a number (sometimes greater than 9).

Here is a list of strings:

```
y = c("Hearing #3: The document states in Article ABC 3 Section 9 line 10 that...",
  "Hearing #3: The document states in Article ABC 31 Section 9 that...",
  "Hearing #3: The document states in Article ABC 3.1 Section 9 that...")
```

Now I cut everything off before the word `Article` that starts the phrase I am interested in:

```
z = substr(y, gregexpr("Article", y)[[1]][1], nchar(y))

> z
[1] "Article ABC 3 Section 9 line 10 that..."   "Article ABC 31 Section 9 that..."  "Article ABC 3.1 Section 9 that..."
```

So far so good, but now I need to recognize the first number (not digit) after the word `Article`:

```
> substr(z, 0, regexpr(pattern='[0-9]', z)[1][1])
[1] "Article ABC 3" "Article ABC 3" "Article ABC 3"
```

That doesn't quite do it, so I've tried to think of a way to do it via positioning with another `gregxepr`:

```
gregexpr(pattern='[0-9]', z)
```

I can't figure out how to do it this way and I'm not even sure that I'm going about this the correct way.

The desired output is:

```
[1] "Article ABC 3" "Article ABC 31" "Article ABC 3.1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_extract` from `stringr` to extract the substring from 'Article' to the numeric part including the `.`

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(y, 'Article[^0-9]*[0-9.]+')
 #[1] "Article ABC 3"   "Article ABC 31"  "Article ABC 3.1"
```

Or with `sub`, we match the `Article` followed by 0 or more non-digits (`[^0-9]*`) followed by one or more numeric characters (`[0-9.]+`), use that a capture group by placing inside parentheses.  It can be used as replacement (`\\1`)

```
sub('^.*(Article[^0-9]*[0-9.]+).*', '\\1', y)
#[1] "Article ABC 3"   "Article ABC 31"  "Article ABC 3.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could fix your problem by adding a negated class after looking for the number.

```
substr(z, 0, regexpr('[0-9][^0-9.]', z))
# [1] "Article ABC 3"   "Article ABC 31"  "Article ABC 3.1"
```

It would be alot simpler to use `sub` for this task:

```
sub('.*(Article\\D*[0-9.]+).*', '\\1', y)
# [1] "Article ABC 3"   "Article ABC 31"  "Article ABC 3.1"
```